# Analysing text in R

Tags: r

I am trying to take data that belongs to a wellknown person speech from the web. First  I go to page and open it's source and I have paste it's html link to R and make it read.

after I have view the data. here how it seems>

```
name type  Value   
<html> list[2] (S3:xml_document,xml_node) List of length 2
```

that was the code

```
list <- read_html("https://linkoftext/")
```

How should I deal with it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is very unclear (deal with what?), please read and edit your question according to: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You should dig into the [`rvest` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/index.html) documentation.